# PHP keep first 6 items in an array and drop the rest

Tags: php

I am wondering how I can drop any array items that come after a certain number like 6. Is there something in PHP that enables you do do it? Or is it a custom function that needs to be written

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) for this purpose. For example:

```
$testArray = range(0, 10);

// Ensure there are at least six items in the source array.
if(count($testArray) >= 6) {
   // Grab the first six items.
   $firstSixItemsFromArray = array_slice($testArray, 0, 6);
}
```

Comment: What will happen if there are only 4 items?

Comment: No problems if there are less items in the sliced array then expected. You get as much as possible, for example array_slice( array(1,2), 0, 4) gives you array(1,2).

Comment: You dont need to slice if count($testArray) == 6. Anyway PHP already do this validation (you duplicate the if). So i recommand to remove this if...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to take the first six elements of an array, based on position in the array, then [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice) or [array_splice](http://php.net/array_splice) is the way to go.

```
array_splice($array, 6);
```

If you want to keep all elements with value less than 6, you could do something like:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($v) { return $v <= 6; });
```